# What is the server-side timeout in RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, timeout, rabbitmq

Going to http://rmq.example.com:15672/#/connections shows the open connections and their properties. One property is called "timeout."  For connections that were made using the RabbitMQ Java client, this value is set to 600.  For connections that were made using the `node-amqp` library, it's blank.

I can't figure out how to change it or necessarily even what it does.  In the Java library, there is a `ConnectionFactory` with a method `setTimeout`, but this sets the timeout in ms passed to `Socket.connect`, i.e. it's a client side timeout that doesn't make it to the server (and indeed it does not agree with the 600s displayed on RMQ's page).  I have also tried adding `timeout`, `connectionTimeout` and `connection_timeout` as client properties, but these do not affect `timeout`.  Indeed, they show up in client properties separately (checked via REST API):

```
"client_properties":{"connectiontimeout":"40000",
"connectionTimeout":"30000",
"connection_timeout", ... }
```

I don't know whether the number "600s" is sent from a client or is a server-default, or even what it does.  I'm looking through the source of both the Java library and `node-amqp` in favor of some evidence, but wanted to ask if anyone has more higher level knowledge of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the heartbeat. The only place this synonymizing is made apparent is the [man page for rabbitmqctl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html):

```
timeout
    Connection timeout / negotiated heartbeat interval, in seconds.
```

In the Java client this is set via `ConnectionFactory.setRequestedHeartbeat(int seconds)`.  I've read that the heartbeat is necessary for the server to know when a connection dies, however I don't know why this is the case, as AMQP is an application-layer protocol, not a transport-layer, and the transport layer manages when a connection starts and ends.